Points of interest for Wuhan 2018 using Baidu
I would like to ask if someone can help me download points of interest (POI) from Baidu for Wuhan for the year 2018. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the website (I do not live in China) and the OpenStreetMap doesn't contain nearly the ammount of POI found in Baidu for that year.
If there is an english version of Baidu (from my experience there isn't) feel free to post it.
All in all, what I would like to ask is if someone can download the dataset on my behalf.

Is it open data?

yes, as long as someone can understand the language to download them

Really open data with the meaning of http://opendefinition.org ?

I can't be 100% sure but I have seen countless authors (from China) using the data for their research. So the data are either fully open accessed or for research purposes.

You can manually list tourist spots, recreational sites, scenic spot and other point of interest by manually searching, specially using Chinese search engines like Baidu, as I did here

Although not from Baidu directly, and not for all China, I found this dataset on Github.
